# In memory archive with ZipFoundation

Tags: zipfoundation

As stated on the link https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation#in-memory-archives, it should be possible to create in memory archive, still I am unable to find appropriate init method of the Archive class. Am i doing something wrong or this is not yet released?

I have seen the [PR](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/pull/143) but still i cant see why this is in the documentation on the github page.

When will this feature be released?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the author:

weichsel commented on 28 Feb • 
Hi,

The GitHub project page shows the state of README.md in the development branch (which is the default branch of the project).
The feature is very new and there is no tagged release yet.
If you want to use/test in-memory archives, please point your package manager to development.

Please also note that this feature is only available if you are targeting Swift 5 or newer. If you are integrating via Carthage, you will have to manually set the SWIFT_VERSION of the ZIPFoundation.xcodeproj to 5 manually. It is currently set to 4 for compatibility reasons. (Carthage does not provide a way to specify the language version).

Comment: I am struggling to extract in in memory can you post some code?